# Type Ahead Combo

Tags: vb.net, combobox

Perhaps you can help me. I am writing a windows application in VB.Net.

My client wants an intelligent combo box with type ahead capability. For example let’s I have a list of companies. I want to find my company “MetaPro”. With the Microsoft combo box if you type in the first letter of the name it will bring up first one starting with that letter. For example I type in “M” it will bring up “Mass. Dept. of Ed.”, I then type in “E” I get the first one starting with “E” maybe “E, G & G” where I want the first one starting with “ME”.

Perhaps there is an open source solution to this or I could create a custom control. But I don't know how. Any help or guidence would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok no one has giving me an answer. I would like to look into third party controls. I'd like to find something with just the drop down control and maybe a few other controls. I don't want to but a big suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In design view, change the AutoCompleteSource to ListItems and AutoCompleteMode to SuggestAppend for the comboBox.

Comment: This is certainly a big improvement over what I had and it may be acceptable to them. What I had wanted was for the first item to pop-up in the combo as you type the letters. For example I type "M" I see "Mass ..." I type "E" I see "MEEI" I type "T" then I see "MetaPro"

Comment: SuggestAppend should do that, assuming you have those values in the list already.

Comment: I see now that it worked fine DropDown style but not DropDownList. I need something that works with a DropDownList.

Comment: A combobox dropdownstyle of dropdownlist does not allow you to type in the control.  To do what you are looking to do, you need to set the combobox's dropdownstyle to dropdown so you can type.  Or you can add a text field to the form and do some code on the key pressed event for the textbox that displays an item in the combobox.